# ReactJS Template component

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a basic document editing application.

Each document has a data model, which is a plain javascript object. I want to have numerous possible templates for each document, where a template is an HTML form on the server. When the user switches the template for a document, the template HTML is retrieved from the server, and current model values are populated into the inputs.

How would one do something like this in react? I was thinking of creating a component for each template, which looks something like this:

```
var TemplateOne = React.createComponent({
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
        margin: "0.5in",
        layout: "portrait"
    };
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <Page margin={this.props.margin} layout={this.props.layout}> 
        <input name="foo" value={this.props.data.foo} onChange={this.prop.updateModel} />
        <input name="bar" value={this.props.data.bar} onChange={this.prop.updateModel} />
        <input name="car" value={this.props.data.car} onChange={this.prop.updateModel} />
      </Page>
    );
  }
});


var TemplateTwo = React.createComponent({
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      margin: "1in",
      layout: "landscape"
    };
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <Page margin={this.props.margin} layout={this.props.layout}> 
        <input name="foo" value={this.props.data.foo} onChange={this.prop.updateModel} />
        <input name="zap" value={this.props.data.zap} onChange={this.prop.updateModel} />
      </Page>
    );
  }
});
```

I would also have a `Document` component, which passes down its model state in the form of the `data` prop, as well as potentially `margin` or `layout` props to the `Template` components. The `updateModel` prop is also passed down from the `Document` component to the templates, and it updates the state of the `Document` model.

Ideally, each of the `Template` components is in a separate file, because the markup for each of the templates is potentially hundreds of lines long, due to very specific form requirements, and I have 20+ templates( with a lot more on the way ).

How could I "fetch" these components from the server? Most resource I have found mention calling React.renderComponent twice, once on the server, and in the browser. Does that mean that I have to include each template in my client javascript? Can I send the component itself over AJAX?

I am still very new to this, and would appreciate any resources that could help me think through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution for getting JavaScript asynchronously will work for this.  This includes require.js, webpack, and other loaders.

When you're getting a template from the server, you can set the Document to show a "loading" template, and when the new template is downloaded, you can switch it to that template.

As long as the combined, minified, gzipped size is under ~200kb, you probably don't need to worry and can just include all of this in your initial payload.

Consider that when you do the templates asynchronusly, there's a delay between the intent to change templates and the time the user sees the template.  If it's all upfront, template switching becomes instant.